# Regularity of level sets of Sobolev derivatives

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I am interested in the regularity of the sets

$$U_{\lambda}:=\{x: |\nabla^k u(x)|> \lambda \}$$

for a function $u\in W^{k,p}(R^d)$ with compact support. We can choose a lower semicontinuous version of $\nabla^k u$, so we can assume that $U_{\lambda}$ is open.

I am interested if on can claim that the boundary of $U_{\lambda}$ has measure zero for a.e. $\lambda$? Furthermore, what can we say about $U_{\infty}=\cap U_{\lambda}$, can it be any $G_{\delta}$ measure zero set, or it should have a special structure?

Comment: Can you say something about motivation? The function $|\nabla^k u|$ can be almost any function in $L^p$ so the structure of the level sets will be just the structure of the level sets of $L^p$ functions. Much more can be said about the structure of the level sets of $u$, but I am not sure if this is of interest to you.

Comment: That is what I expected. My motivation was looking for solutions to $\Delta u = 1_{U}(x)$, where $U$-is an open set with fat boundary. The obvious choice $u(x)=c |x|^2 1_U(x)$ does not seem to be in $W^{2, p}$, so I thought there may be some regularity property on $U$ for function $u$ to exist.

Comment: Assume that $U$ is bounded. Since $\chi_U\in L^p$, $1<p<\infty$, the equation $\Delta u = \chi_U\in L^p$ has a solution $u\in W^{2,p}_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfying $\nabla^2 u\in L^p$.